# How can I restrict a user account from pulling and running docker containers on a VM?

Tags: docker, security, google-cloud-platform

I have a GCP VM instance. I want only certain users to be allowed to pull images and run docker containers on the instance. How can I restrict this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just make sure those users are the only ones in the `docker` group (or whichever it is that has permissions to `/var/run/docker.sock`).

Comment: Also remove those users from sudo.